# Why is @contextmanager used only for self-contained functions?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I am reading the *Python Cookbook* where the following is mentioned:

> `@contextmanager` is really only used for writing self-contained
>   context-management functions. If you have some object (e.g. a file,
>   network connection, or lock) that needs to support the `with`
>   statement, you still need to implement the `__enter` and `__exit__`
>   methods separately.

I can't quite understand this. Why can't we use a file object with a context-management function? Aren't functions decorated with `@contextmanager` equivalent to classes with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you've got a class:

```
class DatabaseCursor(object):
    ...
```

and you want to add context manager functionality to it. Where would you put `@contextmanager`?

Not here:

```
@contextmanager
class DatabaseCursor(object):
    ...
```

Not here:

```
class DatabaseCursor(object):
    @contextmanager
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
```

Not here:

```
class DatabaseCursor(object):
    @contextmanager
    def __enter__(self):
        ...
```

Nowhere, really. `@contextmanager` doesn't help you add context manager functionality to existing classes. You can't even use `@contextmanager`-decorated functions as base classes, because the implementation doesn't actually create a class. If you want your file-like object or database cursor or network connection or other closeable resource to support use as a context manager, you have to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` directly.

Comment: Understood. But why is he using the term 'self-contained' function? What does it mean?